# WPF Binding error: Attached Dependency Property not found

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, dependency-properties

I am trying to resolve a number of frequently occurring data binding errors as given below

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Active' property not found on 'object' ''FrameViewModel' (HashCode=55649279)'. BindingExpression:Path=Active; DataItem='FrameViewModel' (HashCode=55649279); target element is 'ContentControl' (Name='HeaderBorder'); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')
```

I have an attached dependency property Active

```
public bool Active
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)GetValue(ActiveProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ActiveProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ActiveProperty
       = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Active", typeof(bool), typeof(Card));
```

The binding is set in theme files in a control template

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="FrameHeader" TargetType="ContentControl">
.....
.....
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Active}" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="HeaderBackground" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource SelectedHeaderBrush}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Active}" Value="False">
            <Setter TargetName="HeaderBackground" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource HeaderBrush}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

The control template is used in a content control as shown here (can be seen in the error as well)

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="Card" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <ContentControl Template="{DynamicResource FrameTemplate}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ContentControl Template="{DynamicResource FrameHeader}" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="HeaderBorder" >
                <Border Style="{DynamicResource BorderTop}">
                    <DockPanel>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="UpperLeftContent" 
                                          DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                                          Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=icush:Frame},    
                                                               Converter={StaticResource WatchListLockoutTimerVisibilityConverter},    
                                                               Path=UpperLeftContent}" 
                                          Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=icush:Frame},  
                                                            Converter={StaticResource WatchListLockoutTimerConverter},    
                                                            ConverterParameter={StaticResource LockoutTimerRadius},
                                                            Path=UpperLeftContent}"
                                          />
                        <TextBlock x:Name="Header" 
                                   Style="{DynamicResource Header}" 
                                   Text="{Binding Path=Title}" />
                    </DockPanel>
                </Border>
            </ContentControl>
            <ContentControl Template="{DynamicResource FrameBody}" Grid.Row="1" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
        </Grid>
    </ContentControl>
</ControlTemplate>
```

I have spent a lot of time trying to figure out if the DependencyProperty is missing anything or if the binding is set incorrectly but to no avail.
The application works as expected but I'm trying to get rid of such binding errors.
The error goes away if I remove the binding in XML but that is not the solution I'm looking for.
There might be something wrong with the binding.

I have looked at several other posts, read material and book chapters on Dependency Properties and binding and I can't find any obvious mistake. I have even used snoop but didn't get any additional information from that too.
Some of the things I've looked at are given below

[BindingExpression path error: property not found on 'object'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382164/bindingexpression-path-error-property-not-found-on-object)

[System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: property not found on object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19228677/system-windows-data-error-40-bindingexpression-path-error-property-not-found)

[WPF Error 40 BindingExpression path error: property not found on 'object'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16173869/wpf-error-40-bindingexpression-path-error-property-not-found-on-object)

http://wpftutorial.net/DependencyProperties.html

http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/what-is-this-datacontext-you-speak-of/

[Is there a way to determine where a WPF Binding is declared/created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14510931/is-there-a-way-to-determine-where-is-a-wpf-binding-declared-created/14523290#14523290)

[WPF slow performance - many DataItem=null binding warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17492359/wpf-slow-performance-many-dataitem-null-binding-warnings)

Any ideas of what could be going wrong and how I can get rid of the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem here was that for attached properties you need to enclose the attached property in parenthesis, something which was missing in my code.
MSDN [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752300.aspx#Path_Syntax), found in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53301/can-you-bind-a-datatrigger-to-an-attached-property) pointed to by @Rachel,  refers to this requirement.

I was also missing the namespace prefix for the card class. After creating the namespace prefix `local` I changed the code to the following

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(local:Card.Active)}" Value="True">
        <Setter TargetName="HeaderBackground" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource SelectedHeaderBrush}"/>
</DataTrigger>
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(local:Card.Active)}" Value="False">
        <Setter TargetName="HeaderBackground" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource HeaderBrush}"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

This is all that was needed!

Comment: It's worth emphasizing that you must include `Path=` part for attached properties. Otherwise you could see the very same binding error when working with templates and stuff.

Answer (score 8):

WPF binding errors aren't always the easiest thing to read, but break it up by the colons/semi-colons/periods, and read it backwards:

- target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')
- target element is 'ContentControl' (Name='HeaderBorder');
- DataItem='FrameViewModel' (HashCode=55649279);
- BindingExpression:Path=Active;
- 'Active' property not found on 'object' ''FrameViewModel' (HashCode=55649279)'.
- BindingExpression path error:
- System.Windows.Data Error: 40 :

This can be read as:

- Somewhere you are trying to bind a property called `NoTarget`
- This property is located on a `<ContentControl>` with `Name="HeaderBorder"`
- The DataItem (`DataContext`) behind that UI object is of type `FrameViewModel`
- The property you are trying to bind is called `"Active"`
- The `Active` property is not found on `FrameViewModel`
- The rest of the stuff is usually ignorable

Normally I'd suggest you look in your code for something that looks a bit like this:

```
<ContentControl Name="HeaderBorder" NoTarget="{Binding Active}" />
```

and that will be where your problem is for this error message

But, in your case the problem property is `NoTarget`, which is apparently something special to WPF (I learn something new all the time!) related to the triggers.

A Google quick search returns [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53301/302677), which suggests the problem is caused by not using the correct syntax for binding to an attached property.

Try writing the binding for your attached property with parenthesis, like this

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(local:Card.Active),...
```

(I'm not entirely sure if this will work because I thought attached dependency properties had to be attached to UI objects, and you have yours attached to a `Card` object which sounds like a data object. But I could be wrong, or have misunderstood your code :))

Comment: Hi Rachel,  
Thanks for your response. I have seen your answers for a couple of other similar errors and those helped in reading the error.  
If you see the last block of code posted above you will find the ContentControl with the Header Border  
`<ContentControl Template="{DynamicResource FrameHeader}" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="HeaderBorder" >`  
But there is no property `NoTarget`. That is part of the error.  
`FrameViewModel` is in fact the DataContext but the Active property is defined in the class Card instead, as shown in the code above.  
Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Comment: @user3137730 Sorry, I realized that `NoTarget` means something special in WPF (no property targetted) and just finished updating my answer. Does the updated answer help?

Comment: I tried using the parenthesis both with and without the Card class but both approaches don't resolve the error. Using card with the property I get a compile time error that _Card is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project._ and trying to run the project causes error in merging resource dictionaries.  
Not using card gives the same binding error for `(Active)`.
You are right that `Card` is a data object. I think you've got the hang of my code right. Only problem now is to find the problem ;)

Comment: @Tushar If you've built your DP right, you should be able to do something like `<TextBlock local:Card.Active="True" />`

Comment: I was finally able to resolve all of these errors. Your suggestion of using parenthesis with attached properties was the correct solution albeit with the addition of namespace prefix for the `Card` class. I tried to use the `Card` class with the namespace prefix yesterday before posting the question here but was missing the parenthesis. Not using the namespace prefix was the reason I was getting the error `Card is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project.`  
I'm marking your answer as correct and am also putting down the exact solution myself.  
Thanks a lot!